# Creating a foreign key constraint in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA. I'm trying to create a relationship between 2 classes, where one is `User` class, which has a `user_id` field as the primary key. The other class is `Party`. I want it to have a `user_id` field which will reference to the `User` class with a foreign key constraint.

I tried looking out on tutorials but I didn't fully understand how do I reference to a field in a different class. I tried using `@OneToOne(targetEntity=User.class, mappedBy="user_id")` and placing it above the `user_id` field in the `Party` class, but it produced an error saying that it couldn't find the `user_id` field.

What could be the problem?

Comment: which db/dilect you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The `mappedBy` is referring to the field in the target class. Try having a `User` field in the `Party` class, and the other way around. Then annotate the user in the party class with `@OneToOne(mappedBy="party")`.

```
public class User {
  Party party;
}

public class Party {
  User user;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="party")      
  public User getUser() {
  ...
}
```