# JPA: foreign Id is not automatically set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, relationship

I have two Classes, first the "aggregator/owner/whatever"class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = 
  FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Workspace> workspaces;
```

here the "aggregated":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workspace")
public class Workspace {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue()
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_project", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey)
  private Project project;
```

Here some example structure that I want to persist:

```
Project
{
  description:"SOMETHING",
  id:null,
  name:"Project Name",
  workspaces:[{id: null, name: "Somenthing", description: "Workspace Name", }]
}
```

I Receive here:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("projectRest")
public class ProjectRestController {

  @PostMapping("/create")
  public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Project project) {
    try {
        service.insert(project);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }      
  }
```

I don't change anything until I save in a class like that:

```
public void save(Project model) throws RuntimeException {
    this.getSession().persist(model);
}
```

It saves everything like I want in my DB, except by the id_project relationship column on my workspace table
So, my workspace is losing its project reference and I don't know what I doing wrong

Comment: since you dont quote how you associate the objects that you pass to em.persist then not much anyone can say.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684963/creating-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-jpa-and-hibernate this post

Comment: @NeilStockton It's because I don't do nothing explicit, I receive the Project object with its workspaces in my controller object and I dont do anything else. I need to do something more?

Comment: I've no idea what "nothing explicit" is. You have a 1-N BIDIRECTIONAL relation, so you have to set BOTH SIDES of the relation before calling persist . Have you done that? because not showing that code means we have no idea

Comment: @Akash I already have mapped the workspaces on my project class and in my workspace class I have a ManyToOne annotation, that doesn't allow using mappedBy attribute... But maybe I didn't get your poin, I understood?

Comment: @NeilStockton, yes I have  cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST  at my Project object, It's needed on my Workspace object too? Sorry I didn't know that "nothing explicit" meaning nothing in english, I was trying to say that I don't have nothing more programmed in my code about this...

Comment: @diegocolli could you share what database are you using?  also the create table script for project and workspace table, tnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that is expected , You are having a bidirectional relationship which requires each part of the relationship to have a reference to the other part, your project has a workspace inside it but the opposite is not true.

To solve the issue either you go with unidirectional relationship or you retrieve the workspace object and set the project in it

```
public void save(Project model) throws RuntimeException {
    Workspace workspace = model.getWorkSpace();
    workspace.setProject(model);
    this.getSession().persist(model);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, now it works ... But does not it weird? I just do not know why this work is necessary. I mean wouldn't that be the expected behavior?

Comment: @diegocolli this is logical , the goal of the bidirectional relation is to retrieve any object from the other , you cannot ask hibernate to do that for you since it will need to do extra work and this will affect the performance, so i think this makes sense